# Angular KendoGrid excelExport event. Add custom column

Tags: javascript, angular, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, export-to-excel

I'm using the excelExport event for KendoGrid to manipulate some column data before exporting it. Is it possible to add a new column in between two existing columns?

This is the code I have right now to manipulate some dates. I want to add a new column after the first one.

```
    exportDataToExcel(e) 
    {
        const sheet = e.workbook.sheets[0];
        const datePipe = new DatePipe('es-AR');
        for (let rowIndex = 1; rowIndex < sheet.rows.length; rowIndex++) {
            const row = sheet.rows[rowIndex];
            const timestamp = new Date(row.cells[0].value);
            row.cells[0].value = datePipe.transform(timestamp, this.dateFormatColumns);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

By default the Grid export its current columns. However, this can be changed by defining the `<kendo-grid-excelexport-column>` component inside the `<kendo-grid-excel` component.

> The columns defined between the `<kendo-grid-excel` have higher priority when exporting to Excel. That is why they will be visible only in the exported Excel.

```html
<kendo-grid ...>
    <kendo-grid-column field="ID"></kendo-grid-column>
    <kendo-grid-column field="Categories"></kendo-grid-column>
     
    <kendo-grid-excel fileName="Products.xlsx">
        <kendo-excelexport-column 
            field="ProductName" 
            title="Product Name">
        </kendo-excelexport-column>
        <kendo-excelexport-column
            field="UnitPrice"
            title="Unit Price"
            [cellOptions]="{ format: '0.00$' }">
        </kendo-excelexport-column>
      </kendo-grid-excel>
</kendo-grid>
```

For more details check the following article:

https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/export/excel-export/#toc-specifying-exported-columns